# Changing Theme Dynamically

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I have recently upgraded my vuetify version to 2.0. According to [new documentation about theme](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/customization/theme/#light-and-dark), we need to set `dark` in `vuetify.js`. I set the value of `dark` in vuex and when I update the variable, `vuetify.js` does not get the updated value.

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import Vuetify from 'vuetify/lib';
import 'vuetify/dist/vuetify.min.css';
import 'material-design-icons-iconfont/dist/material-design-icons.css';
import store from '../store';

const { getters } = store;

Vue.use(Vuetify);

export default new Vuetify({
  icons: {
    iconfont: 'md'
  },
  theme: {
    dark: getters.isDark
  }
});
```

How can I get the updated value of `dark` from vuex?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think you missed the part where toggling is mentioned.

> ...Will dynamically change when toggling `$vuetify.theme.dark`...

You just need to set `this.$vuetify.theme.dark = true/false` in your function where you toggle the dark theme.

`vuetify.js`:

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import Vuetify from 'vuetify/lib';
import 'vuetify/dist/vuetify.min.css';
import 'material-design-icons-iconfont/dist/material-design-icons.css';

Vue.use(Vuetify);

export default new Vuetify({
  icons: {
    iconfont: 'md'
  },
  theme: {
    dark: false
  }
});
```

Function that should toggle the dark theme:

```
toggle(isDark) {
      this.$vuetify.theme.dark = isDark;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just for the people which want to swap out the whole theme with another theme. The article https://betterprogramming.pub/changing-application-theme-dynamically-in-vuetify-js-c01d640699c4 depictures it quite nicely and uses the following logic to swap out the theme by a completely different theme:

```
    setTheme(theme) {
      // close menu
      this.menu = false;
      const name = theme.name;
      const dark = theme.dark;
      const light = theme.light;
      // set themes
      Object.keys(dark).forEach(i => {
        this.$vuetify.theme.themes.dark[i] = dark[i];
      });
      Object.keys(light).forEach(i => {
        this.$vuetify.theme.themes.light[i] = light[i];
      });
      // also save theme name to disable selection
      this.$vuetify.theme.themes.name = name;
    }
  }
```

Comment: Be aware that this change in vuetify 3. It is then `vuetify.theme.global.current.colors[key] = themeColors[key];`