# Change Vuetify Theme according to API Request Response

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js, vuex

I was wondering if it's possible to change the theme colors according to a API Request response?
I need to do this because I want the admin to choose the theme for all its users of the app.
I've already created the themes objects on the vuetify.js file and the request method. Now I just need somehow to change the chosen theme according to the api request value. Is this possible?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Changing Theme Dynamically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61964442/changing-theme-dynamically)

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in 2 different methods.

**Method 1:**
1.2 supports CSS variables a.k.a customProperties. You have to enable `customProperties` in Vuetify configuration. This will generate css variables and you can consume them in the stylesheet. The values can also be dynamically assigned using javascript. You can refer [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Using_CSS_custom_properties).

```
Vue.use(Vuetify, {
 options: {
   customProperties: true
 }
})
```

**Method 2:**
In the main.js file, before initiating the vuetify, you can hit and get the theme from API and then initialize.

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import Vuetify from 'vuetify/lib';

Vue.use(Vuetify);

const renderApp = async () => {
  const { theme } = await api.getTheme();
  const vuetify = new Vuetify({
    theme,
  });

  new Vue({
    vuetify,
  }).$mount('#app');
};

renderApp();
```

Comment: The 2nd method is kinda working for me, but it's not letting me use the await keyword, because of that I get a promise. Do you know how to make vuetify.js async? Thanks

Comment: Is there a way to make this inside the vuetify.js instead of the main.js? I'm exporting vuetify to main.js in the vuetify.js, and there's where I need to run the api request async.

Comment: You can try updating like this after initiated. `this.$vuetify.theme.themes.light=theme`.

Comment: That also doesn't work inside the vuetify.js. Nothing happens

Answer (score 0):

You can directly set the `theme` property within the `$vuetify` object and it will update the current rendering theme.

```js
// Within a vue component / plugin

const newLightTheme = await axios.get('/api/theme')
// Programatically update light theme
this.$vuetify.theme.themes.light = newLightTheme
// Same for dark
this.$vuetify.theme.themes.dark = newDarkTheme

// Also work with property within a theme
this.$vuetify.theme.themes.light.primary = '#123456'
```

A good source to read: https://betterprogramming.pub/changing-application-theme-dynamically-in-vuetify-js-c01d640699c4